# Reference to array returns it's length after push operation

Tags: javascript

I have a map where my keys are `strings` and values are `Array`.

```
let map = new Map();

map.set("a", []);

map.set("a", map.get("a").push(1)); // reference to array returns it's length: 1
```

Is there any reason why the design is like this?

Comment: Check out the docs to see what `.push` returns (hint: it's not the original array)

Comment: If it did, though, why set back to the same array object at all? `map.get("a").push(1);` by itself will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

That's why you get `1` because you only have one element. Since array can be modified by reference, you can do it like this below:

```
let map = new Map();

map.set("a", []);
map.get("a").push(5);
console.log(map.get('a'))
```

Another option you can consider is to use immutable approach so the original array doesn't get changed with ES6 spread syntax or `concat`

```
map.set("a", [...map.get("a"), 1]);
console.log(map.get('a'));

map.set("a", map.get("a").concat(10));
console.log(map.get('a'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`push()` returns the new length of the array, not the array, so that's what you're storing in the Map.

You don't need to use `map.set()` when you push onto the array. `push()` updates the array in place, so it modifies the array that's stored in the `map`. Just write:

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set("a", []);
map.get("a").push(1);
console.log(map.get("a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last line so that your code becomes:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set("a", []);
map.get("a").push(1); // this will push the value 1 to the array in the map.
```

The function Array.prototype.push returns the length of the array after pushing. So, you are getting 1 which is the length of array.

your instruction pushes the value to your desired array, and then returns 1, which you are setting to the map, which you wouldn't want to. Thus, just push it and don't set it to the map.